# Spring Security HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am trying to do a really simple basic authentication with Spring Security. I have configured the namespace properly and there are no Exceptions in the server. In my "servlet.xml" I have got the next for Spring Security:

```
<security:http>
    <security:http-basic></security:http-basic>
    <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>


<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="cucu" password="tas" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <security:user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

It nearly all goes perfect: The methods that are not `POST` doesn't prompt any login form, and the `POST` method prompt it. The problem is, that nor `cucu`, neither `bob` can login there. Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance! ;-)

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it, Spring Security 3

Comment: Can you post the stack trace/output from the actual error?

Comment: Sorry, I think I should be more descriptive. The problem is that I get an 401 unauthorized even when I use for login those two users. Thanks for your time, Gandalf ;-)

Comment: Your question served as maybe the clearest, concise example of configuring HTTP basic auth that I could quickly google. +1 for that :)

Comment: Multi-use question! :D Cheers, man!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Auto-answer

T_T Two days of hitting my head against the code for this...

Looks like it is not a problem of the code. I was using Weblogic with it and Weblogic captures the requests with the "authorization" header, so it doesn't get to my authentication-manager. I tried it with glassfish, and it works perfectly.

Searching for some info, I found an useful entry in the next blog:
http://yplakosh.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-fix-basic-authentication-issue.html

Adding the next line in the config.xml from my Weblogic server(`<security-configuration>` section):

`<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>`

Weblogic will not catch the basic authentication credentials again, so it will be your authentication-manager who will handle it.

I hope it can save some time to anyone :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this solution. I just started running into this issue and found your post after searching Goolgle.

Comment: Hehe, I am really happy for having helped to save you some time ;-)

Comment: It seems that the issue is still true as of 2019.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<http auto-config="true>
   <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
   <http-basic />
</http>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I Tryed also with the auto-config in true, but I think I am missing something else... but don't know what. I think my code is really simple, there should not be problems with that.