# Spring Security, Rest api and Facebook login from mobile device

Tags: java, facebook, spring-security, spring-social

I'm developing a web application that has a REST api. At the moment the Api are protected in the server side trough spring security with a form-login authentication. Recently I also added spring social to allow access with facebook and twitter and all this works. So a user has to be registered to access some endpoint.

Now I have to build a mobile application that has to access the REST api and I was wondering what strategy I should use.

I saw that facebook has a android/ios sdk to allow the authentication on mobile side. So once theuser is authenticaded on the mobile I should do the request to my server so how should I authenticate the user on the server side to access the resources?

If you think that is not a good solution can you give me an advice how I should solve this problem?

Comment: For more secure, you should do authenticate on both mobile and backend sides, never trust frontend. By this case, after authenticated on mobile, you only send access_token to backend API, and then backend need to re-verify that token for more scure. 

Example: AccessGrant accessGrant = new AccessGrant(accessToken); Connection<Facebook> connection = facebookConnectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Your mobile app can login to your API the same way your other client code does, via form-login or spring social.  Simply send the same session ID cookie with your API calls after login.
2. You can allow your app to accept a username and password as HTTP headers via [HTTP-Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691160/spring-security-http-basic-authentication), to save yourself the initial login step.  This might be more useful if you don't need to make a lot of API calls per session.