# enable security check to access wsdl url

Tags: java, web-services, http-authentication

I have created a web service in my machine. Its URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/aaa/test?wsdl
```

I want to enable one feature to it. As soon as the user enters the url in browser, it should ask for the credentials. Can it be done in web services.

If yes, can some one guide how to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: You could add [basic HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) based on an URL pattern, for instance with spring security, as done in this question: [Spring Security HTTP Basic Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2691160/851811)

Comment: @XaviLópez. Thanks.Do I need to add the URL pattern in spring.xml. Can you provide some code sample for the same

Comment: Yes, you'd need to add the `<http>` element in your `applicationContext.xml`. See an [example here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-http-basic-authentication-example/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using Spring, you can easily apply [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to a specific URL pattern with Spring Security. In your `applicationContext.xml`, just add:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

<!-- HTTP basic authentication in Spring Security -->
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/*wsdl?" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider>
       <user-service>
       <user name="someUser" password="somePassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
       </user-service>
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Example taken from [Mkyong's *Spring Security HTTP Basic Authentication Example*](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-http-basic-authentication-example/).

If you'd like to lookup users in a database, you'd need to use a different authentication provider. The [Spring Security reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-auth-providers) mentions `data-source-ref` if you'd like to query the [standard Spring Security user data tables](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#db_schema_users_authorities). If you've already got your own structure, you might be interested in using `user-service-ref` instead, in which you can lookup the users yourself.

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService"
    class="mypackage.MyUserDetailsService">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And code `mypackage.MyUserDetailsService` extending [JdbcDaoImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) and implementing [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html).

Comment: Thanks for the solution.If we have to get the username and password from the database, will it help. If yes, it would be great if you tell that also

Comment: You'd need to provide a different [authentication provider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-authentication). You can use `jdbc-user-service`, which will query some predefined tables in the DB. Or you can also use `user-service-ref` for a custom user lookup. Mkyong also has a good [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) on using `jdbc-user-service`.

Comment: Have you tried just naming the file `applicationContext.xml`? If I remember correctly, it's the default file Spring looks for.

Comment: Oh, and maybe add `<listener> <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class> </listener>` to your `web.xml`