# Spring security BASIC authentication prompts for user/password twice on Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, weblogic12c

I am trying to use BASIC authentication using Spring security.

It works fine on Tomcat. (Prompts once, as expected.) 
But when I deployed on Weblogic 12c, it prompts the user/password dialog twice. The second dialog expects to enter the weblogic admin console user name password. Only if I enter these two credential its able to login.

Any suggestions please ?

web.xml

```
            <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
             "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
             "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

            <web-app>
                <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

                <context-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
                </context-param>

                <filter>
                    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
                </filter>

                <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                </filter-mapping>

                <listener>
                    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
                </listener>

                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                </servlet>

                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>
            </web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

                <context:component-scan base-package="com.jai.spring.security.controller" />
                <import resource="spring-security.xml" />

                <bean id="viewResolver"
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>

            </beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
            <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

                <authentication-manager>
                    <authentication-provider>
                        <user-service>
                            <user name="jay" password="jay" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                        </user-service>
                    </authentication-provider>
                </authentication-manager>

                <http create-session="stateless">
                    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
                    <http-basic />
                </http>
            </beans:beans>
```

Comment: Which url are you invoking when it asks you for authentication?

Comment: where you deployed he application? admin server or another server

Comment: @Andres I tried http://localhost:7001/securitybasic/hello  and also http://localhost:7001/securitybasic  both behaves the same way on weblogic. But both behaves correctly on Tomcat.

Comment: @venergiac I just have only Admin server and no other managed server. I deployed on Admin server.

Comment: bad idea...in production mode Admin server is reserved for admin...now create a dedicated server and try again

Comment: On that case, wouldn't it be easier to start Weblogic on development mode?

Comment: Or in the case you have to use production mode, use the adapter?

Comment: Seems the request intercept by Spring and weblogic independently. the solution provided in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691160/spring-security-http-basic-authentication   will work for you.

Comment: @venergiac Now I have setup a separate managed server and deployed on it. Still this issue remains.

Comment: @Andres My weblogic runs on Development mode.

Comment: @Mani Thanks Mani, it works now when I followed that link.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have to use an adapter:

> As described in the Spring Security Reference, Container Adapters
>   enable Spring Security to integrate directly with the containers used
>   to host end user applications, in this case WebLogic Server.
>
> The integration between a container and Spring Security is achieved
>   through an adapter. The adapter provides a container-compatible user
>   authentication provider, and needs to return a container-compatible
>   user object.
>
> applicationContext-acegi-security.xml is the configuration file for
>   Spring security. For WebLogic Server, WeblogicAuthenticationFilter is
>   added to the list of filters in applicationContext-acegi-security.xml.
>   This filter is responsible for converting the Weblogic principals to
>   Spring GrantedAuthority subjects, based on the mapper. The mapper is
>   configured as a property for the WeblogicAuthenticationFilter, and it
>   is injected at creation time.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24975/security.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add the next code after   section in the web.xml file:

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```