# Spring Security denying all users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to use basic spring security but can't login with any of the two users I setup. It always comes back with "Error 401--Unauthorized"

I have the three following libraries installed for security:

```
spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

The SPRING-SECURITY.XML file contains the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="test" password="test"
                authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

The WEB.XML file contains the following.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Instead of guessing, setup a logger and log `org.springframework.security` on debug level. It will tell you what went wrong and make it easier to understand to problem. If still in doubt add the the log of the full request to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was in weblogic and NOT configuration.

**Solution:**
The only solution I have found to resolve the issue is to add:

```
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
```

into the **config.xml** file:

```
<security-configuration>
...
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
</security-configuration>
```

This configuration will resolve the issue.

**References**

[Spring Security HTTP Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691160/spring-security-http-basic-authentication)

http://yplakosh.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-fix-basic-authentication-issue.html

Answer (score 2):

This is because you secure all the pages, including login page itself. Probably, you also have misconfigured dispatcher servlet and all JSP pages are protected by Spring Security.

Comment: I want to secure all pages. If the user is not authorized it pop's up a HTTP basic login form. Just as the following. http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/spring-security-http-basic.png

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think you should remove auto-config="true"
This effectively enables http basic+form login, where the login page cannot be loaded because you secure even the login page.
This normally should lead to a redirect error.

The 401 Unauthorized error I think might be caused by your browser sending incorrect credentials,
which are stored in its cache.
Try emptying your username/password cache or using a different browser.

Comment: I removed the auto-config="true" and tried clearing cache + used a different browser. But no avail. Not sure if it is weblogic that needs to be configured.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to try

**Option 1:**

Remove the space after "," in `access` attribute

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

---

**Options 2:**

Use SpEL expression as below

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still nothing. :(

Comment: Did you try with 'test' user? Both options not working?

Comment: So funny thing, I took out <http-basic /> and it works, it loads a basic login form that spring generates. Seems to be an issue with spring and weblogic.

I am going to try this a fix I found and apply it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691160/spring-security-http-basic-authentication

Comment: Thank you for your help, you taught me the use-expression="true"